# Sharepoint 2010: search crawl LDF (log file) is getting increase

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

We have scheduled incremental crawl in sharepoint search for all days in a week.But on evrey sunday LDF file in DB is getting increase by approx 100gb.

On sunday some timer job scheduled mentioned below.

1. Health Analysis Job (Weekly, User Profile Service, Any Server)
2. Health Analysis Job (Weekly, Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Timer, Any Server)
3. Health Analysis Job (Weekly, Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Timer, All Servers)
4. Health Analysis Job (Weekly, Central Administration, All Servers)
5. Recycle Bin
6. Cell Storage Data Cleanup Timer Job
7. Health Analysis Job (Weekly, Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application, All Servers)

Could you please help me out to find if issue occuring because of any these timer jobs. or any other reason?